# Is Ruby turning my hash into an Array, if so why?

Tags: ruby

So I'm trying to make a tree data structure, which can be instantiated by a nested hash.

My code is as follows, and should just recursively make nodes out of keys, and children out of their values.

```
class Tree
    attr_accessor :children, :node_name
    #def initialize(name, children=[])
    #   @children = children
    #   @node_name = name
    # end
    def initialize(hashTree)
        @node_name = hashTree.keys[0]
        @children = []
        p node_name
        hashTree[node_name].each do |hash|
            children << Tree.new(hash)
        end
    end
    #...
end

p = {'grandpa' => { 'dad' => {'child 1' => {}, 'child2' => {} }, 'uncle' => {'child 3' => {}, 'child 4' => {} } } }
p p
p Tree.new(p)
```

When I try to run that code I get the following:

```
{"grandpa"=>{"dad"=>{"child 1"=>{}, "child2"=>{}}, "uncle"=>{"child 3"=>{}, "child 4"=>{}}}}
"grandpa"
/Users/Matt/sw/sevenLang/week1/hw-tree.rb:8:in `initialize': undefined method `keys' for ["dad", {"child 1"=>{}, "child2"=>{}}]:Array (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/Matt/sw/sevenLang/week1/hw-tree.rb:12:in `new'
    from /Users/Matt/sw/sevenLang/week1/hw-tree.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
    from /Users/Matt/sw/sevenLang/week1/hw-tree.rb:11:in `each'
    from /Users/Matt/sw/sevenLang/week1/hw-tree.rb:11:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Matt/sw/sevenLang/week1/hw-tree.rb:26:in `new'
    from /Users/Matt/sw/sevenLang/week1/hw-tree.rb:26:in `<main>'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

It looks like each is turning the nested hash into an array, where the key is the first element, and the value is the second element.

Comment: `hashTree` is a hash, and I would hope the `hash` in `hashTree.each do |hash|` is also a hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hashTree[node_name]` is `p["grandpa"]`, and is a Hash:

```
{"dad"=>{"child 1"=>{}, "child2"=>{}}, "uncle"=>{"child 3"=>{}, "child 4"=>{}}}
```

`Hash#each` will yield a two-element array: a key and a value. So if you write

```
hashTree[node_name].each do |hash|
```

and `hashTree[node_name]` is a Hash, `hash` will always be a two-element array. Due to a trick in its grammar, Ruby will auto-splat an array argument if there are multiple formal parameters, so you can also write:

```
hashTree[node_name].each do |name, hash|
```

This will not result in an error. (You do actually still have an unrelated error in logic, as you're skipping a level.)

An error-free version:

```
class Tree
    attr_accessor :children, :node_name
    def initialize(name, hashTree)
        @node_name = name
        @children = []
        hashTree.each do |child_name, hash|
            children << Tree.new(child_name, hash)
        end
    end
end

p = {'grandpa' => { 'dad' => {'child 1' => {}, 'child2' => {} }, 'uncle' => {'child 3' => {}, 'child 4' => {} } } }
p Tree.new("Family", p)
```

This can be shortened by using `map`:

```
class Tree
    attr_accessor :children, :node_name
    def initialize(name, hashTree)
        @node_name = name
        @children = hashTree.map do |child_name, hash|
            Tree.new(child_name, hash)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: `children` should probably be `@children` instead.  Also, `name` inside of the `each` block should probably be changed to be less ambiguous.

Comment: @Makoto: It's a stylistic difference; both `children` and `@children` will do the same thing after initialisation, due to `attr_accessor` (same with `node_name` and `@node_name` in OP's code).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm assuming the hash provided will be a single key => value pair with the key being the root node though. So there is no need to add a name parameter. instead I did: `hashTree[node_name].each do |name, hash| ` 

`   children << Tree.new({name => hash})` 

`  end`
Please forgive the formatting.

Comment: You assume wrongly then: your own example has two key-value pairs (`"grandpa"` and `"uncle"`).